# Link to Apple Appstore and Google play store

Tags: magento-1.8, mobile, toplinks, app

We use magento 1.8.1CE

We have just launched an app in the app store and the google play store.

Now i would like to have, that there a link is beeing shown.
(on phones with android and IOS only)
Like on the example. [image]

How can i do this in magento. Does anyone has an example for this?

Answer (score 1):

To do that you need to do more or less the following:

1. Detect User Agent sent by the visitors browser.
2. Using regex decide if this an Android or iOS device.
3. Have a block inserted in the Header which according to detected device either displays link to App on Google Play Store or Apple's App Store, or displays nothing.